# Getting error:'float' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe

I have used the below code to split my list elements such as:

```
for rl in Rules:
for a,b in rl.items():
    rl[a] = b.split('|')
```

and then I am getting the error "float' object has no attribute 'split'"

I have checked in the list RULE and there exist no Nan, however my understanding is that this error is only found while it has a NaN value.
Can anyone kindly give a solution to be applied before/after the loop which may help in resolving this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because `b` is a `float`.

Comment: Show us some example input data which demonstrates the issue. The error is self-explanatory.

Comment: Add the full code, so it would be better to understand.

Answer (score 0):

What about checking `type(b)` after the second for loop?

```
for rl in Rules:
    for a,b in rl.items():
        if not isinstance(b, float):
            rl[a] = b.split('|')
```

Comment: it is better to use `isinstance` for this kind of checks

Answer (score 0):

This means that `b` is a float value. You cannot call the `split` method on a float value, only a string. I would check the value of each key/value pair in `rl`.